# Are there any disparaging synonyms for 'city slicker'?

Tags: single-word-requests

It seems there are many negative terms for people who live in the country and lack urban experiences: hick, bumpkin, hillbilly, yokel, okie, hayseed, etc.

What about the opposite scenario where a person from the city lacks practical experience in a rural environment?

The closest I can come is 'city slicker' but that is a bit clumsy and doesn't quite capture the essence of naïveté I'm looking for. I'm open to non-English terms as well.

Comment: Well, not exactly it, but there's "dandy".

Comment: In particular, several of @Elian's suggestions in the above-cited thread look like they would fit your situation.

Comment: I can't believe I broke rule #1. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

An *urbanite* could do as a city-dweller, but it is not especially disparaging—or naive. Else *towny/townie* is probably the most adapted.